# apply a ui selectable to the data from load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a load function to load the data. How can i apply the `UI selectable` to the loaded data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.selectable()` in your `load()` call back function:

```
$("div").load("url_here", function(){
   $(this).find("ul").selectable();
});
```

Obviously change `div`, `url_here` and `ul` to variables which suit your code.